# is it possible mix different RHEL OS version in hadoop cluster?

Tags: redhat, rhel7, hadoop, hdfs, apache-spark

we are using the following HDP cluster with ambari ,

list of nodes and their RHEL version

```
3 masters machines ( with namenode & resource manager ) , installed on RHEL 7.2

312 DATA-NODES machines , installed on RHEL 7.2

5 kafka machines , installed on RHEL 7.2
```

now we want to add the following machines to the cluster but with RHEL 7.5

```
85 DATA-NODES machines , should be installed on RHEL 7.5 version

2 kafka brokers machines , should be installed on RHEL 7.5 version
```

so my question is

can we mix in HDP cluster RHEL 7.2 with RHEL  7.5 version ?

Comment: it is never a good idea to mix versions inside a cluster whatever its rôle is. So I  would answer No by default. In facts, it might work until you  try to maintain , update or patch them .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHEL *minor* versions, for example 7.5, contain ["hundreds" of packages](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/401413), come out every few months, and [are supported for a few months](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata). Service packs with mostly fixes, essentially. Expect to upgrade a couple times a year as a part of your patching.

Only stay on a minor version for an extended period of time with a specific reason.

Applications sometimes define specific versions in their prerequisites. Not in this case, [Hadoop mostly just needs Java](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html).

So, default to your usual procedures to apply software updates to a cluster. Probably do a rolling upgrade.

Comment: just to understand better - you recommended to upgrade the RHEL 7.2 in hadoop cluster to 7.5?   , second if we cant upgrade to 7.5 can hadoop cluster works with mix of rhel version ?

Comment: In general, yes upgrade.

Comment: I will tell you why I am worry , we have physical machines , we cant backup them before upgrade , so we have here risks

Comment: Then implementing a recovery plan is likely a more important problem then growing or upgrading the cluster.